# Does doping silicon affect its coefficient of thermal expansion (CTE)?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, thermal-conductivity, electrical-engineering

Everywhere I have searched I always see the CTE of silicon listed as 2.6*10e-6 °C^-1. However, I have silicon that was phosphorus-doped to an ion concentration of of 2.41*10e11 atmos/cm^3, and I would calculate it's linear expansion. Is it ok to use the CTE of silicon or will it be different?

If it's different, how can I find out the new value? Would it increase or decrease for n-type silicon?

Comment: It depends on your reason for wanting to know the CTE.  Stress between layers of doped and undoped semiconductors is a known problem in device design, but that's a small-magnitude situation. If you're just worried about keeping a small chunk of Si in a "container" it's probably not significant.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, "boron doping to a nominal level of 10^20 atoms/cm3 increases the expansion coefficient of Si over the range 293–550 K by 1.1×10^-8/K" (Journal of Vacuum Science & Technology A: Vacuum, Surfaces, and Films  (Volume:9 ,  Issue: 4, p. 2231)(1991). I don't know about phosphorus-doped silicon, but probably CTE change due to doping at your level is also negligible.